# How to Delete a Service Account in Spinnaker FIAT? API to delete Service account in Spinnaker

Tags: spinnaker

Can anyone provide a snippet sample reference on how we could essentially delete a service account?  The doc only shows a POST request on how to create but not amend or delete.  https://www.spinnaker.io/setup/security/authorization/service-accounts/#service-account-roles

Comment: i have updated your question and answered. Is not a bad question. I dont know whom voted it down. but screw them. I hope you set this up soon.

Answer (score 0):

- Obtain the name of the service account to be removed

`curl $FRONT50/serviceAccounts`

- Execute following command to Delete

```
curl $FRONT50/serviceAccounts                                \
  -H "Content-type: application/json"                         \
  -d '{ "name": "service-account-name@spinnaker-domain.net" }' \
  -X DELETE
```

Comment: Hi Andres, just tried your suggestion and got this error:

"status":405,"error":"Method Not Allowed","message":"Request method 'DELETE' not supported"

Comment: it should work with `DELETE to /serviceAccounts/{serviceAccountName}` there is an issue for improvement created by a nice user: https://github.com/spinnaker/spinnaker/issues/5831

Comment: Thanks for this confirmation i think they've finally updated doc and referenced the following                                                                                                                curl -X DELETE http://spin-front50:8080/serviceAccounts/SERVICE-ACCOUNT-NAME

Comment: oh great. I have been working in improvements to the docs but is a bit hard because i am a newbie. I encourage people to contribute and fix the docs